# COALESCE with a Potential Empty Field - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, coalesce

Here's the issue:  When a Patient comes into the doctor's office, they can have their blood pressure taken 3 times.  The first time is bp1; the second is bp2 and the last time is bp3.

I need to find the last time a patient had their blood pressure checked and what it was.  I thought I could use COALESCE(bp3,bp2,bp1).  However; the system doesn't always make the unused fields NULL.  Sometimes, they're empty.

An example of the data would be:

PatientID    bp1    bp2 bp3
12345   140/90  134/30
12346   NULL    128/68  NULL

Then, I thought I'd use COALESCE(NULLIF(bp3,bp2),bp1)  but that isn't working because sometimes the database shows NULL for bp1 or NULL for bp1 and bp3, but there's a blood pressure in bp2.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Word problems are hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to NULLIF each column individually to make the COALESCE statement work.

E.g.,

```
COASLESCE(NULLIF(bp3, 0), NULLIF(bp2, 0), NULLIF(bp1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about case?  I don't know the datatype, so I'm guessing INT

```
case when bp3 > 0 then bp3
     when bp2 > 0 then bp2
     else bp1
end as bp
```

And for string (varchar) datatype

```
case when len(bp3) > 0 then bp3
     when len(bp2) > 0 then bp2
     else bp1
end as bp
```